# delete line which have certain keywords from a json file using bash script

Tags: json, bash, shell

I have a JSON config file and I am trying to remove a certain line from the files using bash commands. find below sample entries in my JSON file and I am removing the entire line using the below command and it's working as expected. I need to remove the ',' also from the line just before this entry to get a valid JSON.

```
sed -i '/ssl_verify_hostname/d' myfile.txt

"ft_ssl":{
  "ssl_ciphers":null,
  "ssl_expected_hostname":null,
  "ssl_identity":null,
  "ssl_issuer_list":[],
  "ssl_password":null,
  "ssl_private_key":null,
  "ssl_trusted_list":[],
  "ssl_verify_host":null,
  "ssl_verify_hostname":null
},
```

Expected Output:

```
  "ft_ssl":{
  "ssl_ciphers":null,
  "ssl_expected_hostname":null,
  "ssl_identity":null,
  "ssl_issuer_list":[],
  "ssl_password":null,
  "ssl_private_key":null,
  "ssl_trusted_list":[],
  "ssl_verify_host":null
},
```

Comment: `sed` is the wrong tool for JSON. Take a look at `jq`.

Comment: @Cyrus unfortunately I don't have this jq available in the servers.

Comment: If you have a hammer and a screw, you don't use the hammer.  You go to a store and get a screwdriver.

Comment: @NevinThomas Bash/shell is definitely the wrong tool to manipulate markup files like JSON. If you don't have access to `jq` or cannot install it, check to see if you have `python` or `nodejs` which deals with JSON natively. Do not manipulate JSON with anything but JSON parsers, even it it look like ok for this special case. It will create issue sooner or later.

Comment: @LéaGris you are 100% right. but unfortunately, I don't have any option as the server owner doesn't want to install any new package.  let me try to talk to him again

Answer (score 4):

Use a `json` parser.  eg:

```
$ cat input

{"ft_ssl": {
  "ssl_ciphers":null,
  "ssl_expected_hostname":null,
  "ssl_identity":null,
  "ssl_issuer_list":[],
  "ssl_password":null,
  "ssl_private_key":null,
  "ssl_trusted_list":[],
  "ssl_verify_host":null,
  "ssl_verify_hostname":null
}}
$ jq 'del( .ft_ssl.ssl_verify_hostname)' input
{
  "ft_ssl": {
    "ssl_ciphers": null,
    "ssl_expected_hostname": null,
    "ssl_identity": null,
    "ssl_issuer_list": [],
    "ssl_password": null,
    "ssl_private_key": null,
    "ssl_trusted_list": [],
    "ssl_verify_host": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    data = json.load(f);
    if 'ssl_verify_hostname' in data['ft_ssl']:
        del data['ft_ssl']['ssl_verify_hostname']

    print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: An equivalent ruby one-liner: `ruby -rjson -e 'data = JSON.load(File.new(ARGV.shift)); data["ft_ssl"].delete("ssl_verify_hostname"); puts JSON.pretty_generate data' file`

Answer (score 1):

Better to use one of the currently 174 JSON tools listed at
[json.org](https://www.JSON.org/json-en.html) ...

But it can be done with `sed`:

```
sed -e '
/,$/!b
$b
N
/,\n[ ]*"ssl_verify_hostname".*/!{
    P
    D
}
s///
' -- file
```

If line does not end with a comma (`,$`) branches (`b`) to end of script.
On match - unless on last line (`$b`) - opens a 2-line window
appending (`N`) next line to current. If no match prints (`P`) and
deletes (`D`) up to newline and resumes, else substitutes (`s///`) the
match for an empty string - the empty regex reusing the last.